# PHP8 and guzzlehttp package

Tags: guzzle, php-8.2

I have updated my local setup with PHP 8.2.13 version, my project is working fine.

I have third party API call within my project which is implemented with guzzleHttp client class. GuzzleHttp version I am using in 6.0

Before I update my PHP version it was working fine, but now its throwing error like -
**Connection refused for URI https://test.com**

In my php.ini below is the setting -
**extension=openssl**

Any help would be so much appreciated

1. I tried upgrading guzzlehttp version to 7.8.1.
2. After that I run composer self-update
3. Next I tried with below commands -
   composer config --global -- disable-tls true
   composer config --global -- ignore-tls-errors true
4. With GuzzleHttp class object I tried with below as well -
   `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([ 'verify' => false, ]);`

Answer (score 0):

*Depends on development environment*

> **XAMPP** (Windows)

1. If you installed php and then **replaced** the **php** folder in the
   **xampp** folder
2. then rename the **php-development.ini** file to **php.ini**.
3. launch XAMPP and in the Apache line select **config -> php.ini**
4. unlock the plugins that will be needed
5. Restart XAMPP
6. Reinstall composer because it is tied to a certain version of php

Comment: I am not using XAMPP or any other combined app.